# The letter <u> in Provençal: when is it [y] and when is it [œ]?

Tags: phonology, romance-languages, occitan

In most dialects of Occitan, the letter <u> is pronounced [y] generally. However, in Provençal it appears to be pronounced [œ] by some speakers some of the time.

This [wikipedia article](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prononciation_de_l%27occitan#Voyelles) states (without a source) that it is a feature of the Rhodanien subdialect in particular.

It doesn't appear to be all words where [y] becomes [œ]. Listening closely to [this Provençal example](https://locongres.org/fr/applications/fonoc/fonoc-echantillons-de-textes), the <u> in words like 'degun' and 'luna' sound like [œ] to my ear, but in 'un' it is clearly [y].

Is it in fact a feature primarily of Rhodanien, as the wikipedia article states, and what rules govern when it is [y] and when it is [œ]?

Comment: I do not have any answer, but the files you link are a linguistic treat! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I wish I knew. The conditioning seems completely inexplicable from that text sample – the only explanation I can think of is that it’s phonemic (however the split may have arisen).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Someone [on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/occitan/comments/gq7y73/the_phonology_pronunciation_of_the_letter_u/) suggested it had to do with contact with the letter <n>, unfortunately that's still only a guess.

Comment: @S.T.Veje That was my initial thought as well, but the feminine indefinite article was (if I recall correctly) pronounced [yn] in the clip, which is also in contact with /n/.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Could be that monosyllabic words are exceptions?

Comment: @S.T.Veje I thought I remembered _luna_ and _una_ being [lœnə] and [ynə], respectively, so both what we might call sesquisyllabic, but also (apart from the initial l-) also completely identical in phonetic context. I suppose it might be that word-initially it remains [y], but that seems an odd conditioning…

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Good point. Both 'punit' and 'dubriguèt' are pronounced with [œ] in the sample, so it isn't word-initially either, and the latter doesn't have an <n> so ... I'm back to having no idea.

Comment: It's always dangerous to generalise from such a small sample, but to me it feels like _lexical stress_ at some points, and _phrasal stress_ at others.